# React Native events do not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I have a trivial react component that only shows a button:

```
<Button onPress={() => console.log("test")} title="Button"/>
```

When I put this button into a project I created with `react-native init`, it works as expected.

However, I have an existing project into which I integrated React Native (0.51.0) manually (because it doesn't use cocoa pods; I followed this guide: https://medium.com/@joshyhargreaves/adding-react-native-to-existing-ios-project-without-cocoapods-6f1ee9106009).

The project seems to work fine: the UI loads, the button gives visual feedback when I tap it. But the buttons `onPress` event is not fired, so it does not log anything.

There are no errors or warnings (except `Class RCTCxxModule was not exported`, but it seems to be safe to ignore this).

I'm now out of ideas of what I could try or how I could debug this issue short of diving into Reacts touch handling code. Here's what I tried:

- Made sure to only have one RCTRootView, and that it is created in the main thread.
- Checked for any suspicious things happening in the remote debugger; everything looks normal (no exceptions thrown or warnings logged).
- Tested a few other components that should fire events; for example, `TouchableOpacity` does not work either.
- Logging something after a timeout does work, so it doesn't seem like anything is deallocated prematurely
- Checking for errors reported by the metro bundler: it doesn't print anything

Any ideas on what I need to do to get my button to print "test" when I tap it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not Debug JS Remotely option enabled. If you don't you have to open React Native Debug Menu Pressing (command / control) + D or shake your device if you are debugging with real device. Then just press Debug JS Remotely and it should appear in the  Google Chrome. Then inspect and open the console. There it is!

Comment: That's what I meant with "Checked for any suspicious things happening in the remote debugger". I did activate remote debugging, set a breakpoint and stepped through the app, but I didn't see any problem with the code (as there is almost no code to debug). I did set the "pause on caught exceptions" checkmark, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Try an alert instead a console.log to see what happen maybe?

Comment: I did try that; didn't work. I'm 99.9% sure that the event is not being called; I tried the log statement (should be the most foolproof test), calling a function with another console.log and a breakpoint in it (the breakpoint was not hit, even though they work in general) and displaying an alert. None of them work (but only in the project where I integrated React manually).

Comment: Does still not working if you use the onPress of TouchableHighLight?

Comment: Nope, I did not find a single UI component with a working event.

Comment: Is stranger, could you share the whole class or file to study it?

Comment: This won't help you, because the JS code is correct - it works in a project i create with `react-native init`. Instead, there is probably something wrong with the way I integrated react in the project, but I have no idea what that could be.

Answer (score 0):

This mite caused by date diff between the host (your computer) and the client (the mobile device)

You can check this by running `adb shell "date" && date`
to see if there is a diff.

If there is one go to your mobile device and toggle `automatic date & time` off and back on.

Then test time diff again as mentioned, if there is no more diff, tap events should work in debug mode

More details in the original [git issue answer by - Alex Ciarlillo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27008#issuecomment-592048282)